# Finding max date for a concatenated field

Tags: sql, concatenation, max

I am trying to take a very large product table that has one row per product status and date, and get down to a table that demonstrates the latest status for each product they own.

I think if I concatenate the account and product columns and then use that to find the max date but I'm stumbling with my code. Would appreciate any insight!

**Example table**

| Account | Product | EffectiveDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | Product A | 5/1/2021 | Live |
| 10000 | Product A | 9/1/2020 | Decomissioned |
| 10000 | Product B | 12/1/2021 | Implementing |

**My goal output would be:**

| Account | Product | EffectiveDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | Product A | 5/1/2021 | Live |
| 10000 | Product B | 12/1/2021 | Implementing |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT X.Account,X.Product,X.EffectiveDate,X.Status FROM
(  
   SELECT E.Account,E.Product,E.EffectiveDate,E.Status,
   ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY E.Product ORDER BY E.EffectiveDate DESC)AS XCOL
   FROM Example_table AS E
)X WHERE X.XCOL=1
```

May be something like this will be suitable

Answer (score 0):

For some DBMS you can use a window function and `qualify`. On others (SQL Server) you can use `top` and a window function.

```
create table T1 (Account int, Product varchar(255), EffectiveDate date, status varchar(255));

insert into T1 (Account,    Product ,   EffectiveDate , "STATUS" ) values
(10000, 'Product A', '2021-05-01', 'Live'),
(10000, 'Product A', '2020-09-01', 'Decomissioned'),
(10000, 'Product B', '2021-12-01', 'Implementing');

-- Snowflake, Teradata, Oracle, others...
select   Account, Product, EffectiveDate, Status
from     T1 
qualify row_number() over (partition by Account, Product order by EffectiveDate desc) = 1
;

-- SQL Server
select top 1 with ties Account, Product, EffectiveDate, Status
from T1
order by row_number() over (partition by Account, Product order by EffectiveDate desc);
```